# How to fix TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_config.Svg.G')

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-native-svg

I'm getting this error in an expo react native project I'm working on. I've updated all packages to match expo SDK 36, so I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_config.Svg.G')
```

Comment: did you found solution for this?